# How does AOP via ninject.extensions.interception relate to ninject?

Tags: .net, aop, ninject-2, interception

1. I understand that ninject.extensions.interception can be used for AOP, but how does this project relate/leverage Ninject?
2. Is it possible to use Ninject for DI and some other framework for AOP?  Does ninject.extensions.interception do something special to make AOP work in context of also using Ninject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ninject does not force you to use any specific AOP framework. But what's unique to he Ninject extension is that the interceptors themselves get injected by Ninject without adding any custom code.